# Initial Velocity Vector Calculation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

A rocket takes off from the origin at time $t=0$ seconds with an initial velocity vector and subsequently subject only to the force of gravity, which we take to be exactly $-9.8$$\frac{m}{s^2}$ in the downward direction.
The rocket reaches its highest point at the point $(11800,8400,1960)$. Find its initial velocity vector:

$vec{r}'(0) = < _, _, _ >$

Im not sure where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start by looking up the equation for motion with a constant acceleration and an initial velocity.  Do you know that?  The maximum altitude comes when the vertical velocity is zero, which gives you the time.

Comment: What is the equation? I understand where that maximum comes from.

Comment: It is usually given as $x=x_0+v_0t+\frac 12at^2$ or something similar.  Have you seen it?

Comment: Thanks for your help i was able to find t using that formula and the rest was easy